# Extra white line in densityplot's output

Tags: plotting

How can I remove the white line in $y=0$? This is my code:

```
Rc = 0.1;
m = 0;
foo[Rp_?NumericQ, tep_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[-Sin[tp] Exp[- Cos[ (tp - tep)]], {tp, 0, 2 Pi}]
DensityPlot[
 foo[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] 
  Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2.3], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.8]]], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRange -> {{-2.3, 2.3}, {-2.3, 2.3}, All}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I remove the white line in y=0

Try  `Exclusions -> None`

```
Rc = 0.1;
m = 0;
foo[Rp_?NumericQ, tep_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[-Sin[tp] Exp[-Cos[(tp - tep)]], {tp, 0, 2 Pi}];
DensityPlot[foo[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]],
 {x, y} \[Element] 
  Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2.3], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.8]]],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotRange -> {{-2.3, 2.3}, {-2.3, 2.3}, All}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DensityPlot[foo[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]],
 {x, y} \[Element] 
  Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2.3], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.8]]],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotRange -> {{-2.3, 2.3}, {-2.3, 2.3}, All},
 Exclusions -> None
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]